# Donut tutorial, weight paint opposite side

Tags: weight-painting

I'm doing the donut tutorial and I'm on the weight painting part but I have a problem. When I try to paint my mesh for the sprinkles, it actually paints the opposite side of my icing.
I tried resetting my normals but nothing (maybe I'm doing it wrong, edit mode -> mesh -> normals -> recalculate outside).

Thank for the help
Best regards,
Wyno

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, sure, you can find my file in my post (at the end)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't correctly recalculate the normals, see, they are flipped. So switch to *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked :)